# How can I save a setting field with multiple checkbox options generated by a foreach loop on a custom wordpress admin page?

Tags: plugins, loop, buddypress, settings-api

```
    function ld_reports_plus_register_submenu_page(){
    add_submenu_page(
        'ld-reports-plus',
        'LearnDash Reports Plus Settings',
        'Report Settings',
        'manage_options',
        'ld-reports-plus-settings',
        'ld_reports_settings_submenu_page'
    );
add_settings_section(
      'bp_reg_fields',                          //Name of the section
      'BuddyPress Profile Fields',                      //Title for the  section
      'ld_report_bp_section_callback_function',                         //Callback function for the section
      'ld-reports-plus-settings'                //Page where the section will be located
  );               
add_settings_field(
    'ldrp_bp_options',                                  //Name of the field
    'BuddyPress Options',                               //Title for the field
    'ld_report_bp_fields_callback_function',                            //Callback function for the field
    'ld-reports-plus-settings',                                 //Page where the field will be located
    'bp_reg_fields' );                             //Section where the field will be located
register_setting( 'ld-reports-plus-settings', 'ldrp_bp_options' );

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ld_reports_plus_register_submenu_page' );

function ld_reports_settings_submenu_page(){  
  echo '<div class="wrap">';     
    echo "<h1>" . __( 'LearnDash Reports Plus', 'ld-reports-plus' ) . "</h1>";
    echo '<form method="post" action="options.php">';        
      settings_fields('ld-reports-plus-settings');
      do_settings_sections('ld-reports-plus-settings');      
      submit_button('Add Report Fields');          
    echo '</form>';
  echo '</div>'; 
}

function ld_report_bp_section_callback_function(){
echo '<p>Add BuddyPress Registration Field data to LearnDash Reports.</p>';
function ld_report_bp_fields_callback_function(){
    $profile_groups = BP_XProfile_Group::get( array( 'fetch_fields' => true ) );
    if ( !empty( $profile_groups ) ) {
    foreach ( $profile_groups as $profile_group ) {
           if ( !empty( $profile_group->fields ) ) {                
               foreach ( $profile_group->fields as $field ) {
                //echo $field->id . ' - ' . $field->name . '<br/>';
         $options = get_option( 'ldrp_bp_options' );
                echo '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $field->id  . '" name="' . $field->name . '" value="1"' . checked( 1, $options[$field->id], false ) . '/>';
                echo '<label for="' . $field->name . '">' . $field->name . '</label>' . '<br/>';
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `xprofile_get_field_data( $field, $user_id, $multi_format)`

```
 * @param mixed  $field        The ID of the field, or the $name of the field.
 * @param int    $user_id      The ID of the user.
 * @param string $multi_format How should array data be returned? 'comma' if you want a
 *                             comma-separated string; 'array' if you want an array.
```